# How should I compare different clustering results when one possible result is a single cluster?

Tags: clustering

I'm attempting to determine the true number of clusters in a small-ish dataset (30 features, 100 observations). I'm clustering the observations by constructing a *k*-nearest neighbors graph, with $k \approx \sqrt{N}$, and then detecting communities using the Louvain modularity optimization algorithm. The way this data is structured, the number of communities should be small, and could potentially be one.

I'm planning on comparing a couple clustering results generated using slightly different parameters each time using a silhouette statistic. I'll calculate the silhouette statistic for each point in each cluster, take the mean of those points to generate a silhouette score for each cluster, and then take the mean of all cluster silhouette scores to generate a silhouette score for each clustering parameter combination (sorry if that's a convoluted explanation).

My issue is that I obviously cannot calculate a silhouette score for just one cluster. So, how could I compare clustering results with multiple communities versus a clustering result with just one community? Should I abandon the mean silhouette score idea?